# How to pass all arguments from __init__ to super class

Tags: python, inheritance, variadic-functions

IS there any magic I can use in Python to to effectively use super constructor by just adding some extra arguments?

Ideally I'd like to use something like:

```
class ZipArchive(zipfile.ZipFile):
    def __init__(self, verbose=True, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor with some extra params.

        For other params see: zipfile.ZipFile
        """
        self.verbose = verbose
        super(ZipArchive, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

And then be able to use the original constructor arguments mixed with some extra stuff from my class. Like so:

```
zip = ZipArchive('test.zip', 'w')
zip = ZipArchive('test.zip', 'w', verbose=False)
```

I'm using Python 2.6, but if the magic can only be achieved in higher version of Python then I'm interested too.

EDIT: I should probably mention that above doesn't work. The error is: `TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
class ZipArchive(zipfile.ZipFile):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor with some extra params:

        * verbose: be verbose about what we do. Defaults to True.

        For other params see: zipfile.ZipFile
        """
        self.verbose = kwargs.pop('verbose', True)

        # zipfile.ZipFile is an old-style class, cannot use super() here:
        zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Python 2 is a little persnickety and funny about mixing `*args`, `**kwargs` and additional named keyword arguments; your best bet is to **not** add additional explicit keyword arguments and just take them from `kwargs` instead.

The [`dict.pop()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) removes the key from the dictionary, if present, returning the associated value, or the default we specified if missing. This means that we do **not** pass `verbose` on to the super class. Use `kwargs.get('verbose', True)` if you just want to check if the paramater has been set without removing it.

Comment: Or `self.verbose = kwargs.pop('verbose', verbosedefaultvalue)`

Comment: @glglgl: indeed, much beter, I forgot `pop()` takes a default.

Comment: You may also want to consider `self.verbose = kwargs.get('verbose', verbosedefaultvalue)` in case you want to look at args that also do the the super class method.

Comment: @Ber: There, made that more explicit.

Comment: That does seem to work in terms of params, but I'm getting `TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj`. And so to my knowledge I cannot inherit from `zipfile.ZipFile` and use `super` as the original class is an old style class :-(. At least on Python 2.6.6.

But thanks I'll use this in some other case.

Comment: @Nux: Then `zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)` will work; same principle applies.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about passing self and though it just won't work.