# How to assign target in custom threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from threading import *
from random import *

class Ant(Thread):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Ant_farm():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self. y = y
        self.matrix = matrix(x, y)
        self.condition = Condition()

    def move(self, ant):
        with self.condition:
            x1, y1 = next_post(ant)
            while self.matrix[x1][y1]:
                self.condition.wait()
            self.matrix[ant.x][ant.y] = False
            ant.move(x1, y1)
            self.matrix[ant.x][ant.y] = True
            self.condition.notify_all()

    def next_pos(self, ant):
        while True:
            choice = {0: (ant.x, ant.y - 1),
                      1: (ant.x + 1, ant.y),
                      2: (ant.x, ant.y + 1),
                      3: (ant.x - 1, ant.y)}
            x1, y1 = choice[randrange(0, 4)]
            try:
                self.matrix[x1][y1]
            except IndexError:
                pass
            else:
                return x1, y1

    def __str__(self):
        res = '\n'
        for i in range(self.x):
            aux = ''
            for j in range(self.y):
                aux += str(self.matrix[i][j]) + ' '
            aux += '\n'
            res += aux
        return res

def matrix(x, y):
    return [[False for j in range(y)] for i in range(x)]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ant_farm = Ant_farm(7, 7)
    for i in range(4):
        # t = Ant(target = ant_farm.move)
        pass
```

I want to run `move` function inside `Ant` threads. I tried to do:

```
t = Ant(target = ant_farm.move)
```

But the interpreter says this:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'target'

I understand the error, but I don't know how to do what I said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass all arguments from \_\_init\_\_ to super class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106662/how-to-pass-all-arguments-from-init-to-super-class), just add a `, **kw` to the definition and pass it on to `Thread.__init__` to forward keyword arguments.

Comment: Did you mean `Ant` or `Ant_farm` in the tried to do bit? It's different to the code.

Comment: `Ant`, I just edit

Comment: Also I want to know if the methods and classes are well designed, because I think that maybe are a little "complex".